# Does NSArray copy objects?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

When I make an `NSArray` using +`[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]`, does it copy those objects? If I release the objects after adding them to the array, will I run into problems?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, it doesn't copy them. It retains them. Yes, you can safely release the objects after adding them to the array.

[The docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-279947), as always, spell this out very clearly:

> Arrays maintain strong references to their contents—in a managed memory environment, each object receives a retain message before its id is added to the array and a release message when it is removed from the array or when the array is deallocated. If you want a collection with different object ownership semantics, consider using CFArray Reference, NSPointerArray, or NSHashTable instead.

Comment: Great answer. Also remember that +arrayWithObjects: returns an unowned ("autoreleased") array, so you must retain it to avoid losing it, but the object in the array will be around as long as the array is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You should know that I search the documentation before posting on Stack Overflow (sometimes, I don't catch everything, though).

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- though that blurb isn't in the reference anymore, FYI.  As far as I can tell, that entire section is gone.  You can only infer it by looking at the subclassing information and a few of the function calls, and that primarily because you pointed me in the right direction.