# Clarification on Objects in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nsobject

If this is a noob question, I apologize in advance. I just want to clarify how the relationship between the objects inside an array relates to the actual object. For example:

```
 UILabel *labelOne = //init stuff

 [self.view addSubview: labelOne];

 [labelArray addObject: labelOne];
```

Now if I change the property of the object inside the array like so:

```
 [[labelArray objectAtIndex:0] setText:@"NEW STRING"];
```

Am I updating just what is inside the array or will it also update my initial UILabel and therefore reflect the change on the view? Are there any situations where the results might differ? (i.e. releasing initial UILabel with object still in the array, etc.)

Comment: It is possible through property of UILabel and using KVO pattern

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does NSArray copy objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258735/does-nsarray-copy-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array stores a strong reference to the object, but doesn't copy it. So there is only ever one label. So the code you showed will update the label's text.

Answer (score 1):

It will change the UILabel you have on screen since NSArray only holds references to objects, it doesn't make copies. So whatever labels you are putting into the array are just references to what you've already created.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will update your initial `UILabel` and therefore reflect the change on the `UIView` as reference of `UILabel` is stored in array.

Answer (score 1):

IT will  update your initial UILabel as NSArray is holding the reference of original UILabel and not there copies

Answer (score 0):

Your `labelArray` will contain pointers to each adding object. And it increment retain counter for each adding object. So `[[labelArray objectAtIndex:0] setText:@"NEW STRING"];` will change `labelOne.text` too, because you reference to one `UILabel` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *labelOne = //init stuff
[self.view addSubview: labelOne];
[labelArray addObject: labelOne];
[[labelArray objectAtIndex:0] setText:@"NEW STRING"];
```

The label which you add to labelArray is the same object as initial labelOne. 
But if you what to avoid such behavior you can add a copy of labelOne to labelArray by using copy method.

```
[labelArray addObject: [labelOne copy]];
```

This will give you a copy of labelOne object in you labelArray. And this copy will not be changed after you change label text. 
So after you get labelOne from array the label will be in initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will change the value of the label text displayed on the view. See here I have simulate the scenario..

Code....

```
    UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 200, 20)];
    labelOne.text = @"Dilip";

    [self.view addSubview: labelOne];

    NSMutableArray *labelArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [labelArray addObject: labelOne];

    [[labelArray objectAtIndex:0] setText:@"Hi Dilip"];
```

And here is the output..

[image]

You can see that instead of text "Dilip" there is displayed text is "Hi Dilip".
The labelArray stores only the reference of the labelOne. so if you change anything in the labelArray affect the labelOne.