# Memory management of NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, memory-management, nsarray

This is My code:

```
NSNumber *tempNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:tempNum,@"A", nil];
tempNum = nil;
NSLog(@"Array :%@",array);
```

and the output is :

```
 Object :(null)
 Array :(
    5,
    A
)
```

Can anyone give the exact explanation whether array save the reference of the object or made copy of object or something else.

Comment: From where "Object:(null)" come?

Comment: NSLog(@"Object :%@",tempStr);, its your string not an array object. Please check it clearly.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh - good catch!

Comment: That is what i am asking that at the time of saving object into array,whether takes the reference or copy the object

Comment: @DharmbirSingh, you are exactly wrong.  Try it yourself.

Comment: @DharmbirSing, why don't you try it for yourself?  You can use the code in my answer as a starting point.

Comment: @Avi Got your point dude. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

NS collection classes, including `NSArray`, keep strong references to the objects added to them.  They do not create copies.

Here's a trivial example to demonstrate:

```
NSMutableString *s = [@"a" mutableCopy];
NSArray *a = @[ s ];

[s appendString:@"b"];

NSLog(@"a = %@, s = %@", a, s);
```

The log will show that both the contents of `a` and `s` are the same, even though only `s` was modified.

Comment: NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];
    NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:tempStr,@"A", nil];    
    NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    [array2 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:0]];
    
    NSString *string2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:0];
    string2 = @"World";
//    [string2 stringByAppendingString:@" World"];
    NSLog(@"Array1 :%@",array1);
    NSLog(@"Array2 :%@",array2);


Output:
Array1 :(
    Hello,
    A
)
Array2 :(
    Hello
)

In this case it makes copy

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: When you perform string2 = @"World" you are overriding the reference to the first object in the array with a new string (World). You are allocating a new string with the value World and assigning it to the variable string2, and not changing the value in the array.

Comment: @Avi Could you tell me suppose i've NSString object not immutable object, and want to add other string to using stringWithFormat method in that case why it's not modifying the array?

Comment: @DharmbirSingh, either you're modifying the same reference as what is in the array, or you aren't.  Where's the code?

Comment: @Avi NSString *s = @"a";
    NSArray *a = @[ s ];
    s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",s, @"Dharm"];
    NSLog(@"a = %@",a);

Comment: @DharmbirSingh: The assignment `s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",s, @"Dharm"];` creates a new instance.  I think you are confusing variables, references and the instances they point to.

Comment: @Avi Thanks Avi got it, You cleared my all concerns.

Answer (score 0):

The array saves a strong reference to the `NSNumber` object, when you nullify `tempNum` the reference to the number is not in the tempNum variable anymore but the object is not deallocated since the array has a reference to it.
More infos here: [Does NSArray copy objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258735/does-nsarray-copy-objects)